# How do I increase the heap size for Netbeans and any app run via Netbeans?

Tags: macos, java

I'm trying to run a well-coded algorithm that tries to solve an NP-Hard problem via NetBeans but I'm running out of heap space.

Is the heap space I'm running out of specific to Netbeans? If so: how do I increase the heap space available to Netbeans?

Or is it specific to the app, as launched from Netbeans? If so: how do I tell Netbeans to launch it with more heap space?

Comment: Heap size is set via an argument to the JVM when you start an application. It's not a system-wide setting. You have to figure out how your specific app is being started and edit the heap size setting there. Might want to consider editing the question to focus on making this change for Netbeans specifically.

Comment: But how can that be? It must have some standard setting, or is an implicit argument passed along when I start an app?

Comment: You are probably right about the edit, but then it becomes an SO-question I'm sure.

Comment: This is definitely an SO question IMO. Not an AD question. The actual answer is specific to Netbeans and very much OS independent.

Comment: Yeah, it became Netbeans-specific. Thanks for the edit, Ian. To whomever it may concern: please move to SO.

Comment: This is certainly on scope here and on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242602/netbeans-default-options-startng-jvm-with-more-memory) and we normally will try to migrate something that _doesn't already have an answer_ if asked by the OP (as @TheUnfunCat has asked). In this case, I doubt SO would want it as worded (but I could be wrong) and we do have a good answer here that relates to how to get inside a package. I'd rather not move it given how well it fits and is answered here almost immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ian C. says, the heap size is Application specific, therefore, here's how you increase it for Netbeans:

1. Right click on the **NetBeans.app** and select *Show content of package*.
2. Inside the package go to **/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/** and open the **netbeans.conf** file.
3. In the `netbeans_default_options` setting, change or add the following options: `-J-Xmx...` (e.g. `-J-Xmx1600M`) or `-J-XX:MaxPermSize=...` (e.g. `-J-XX:MaxPermSize=500M`).
4. Save the file and restart the IDE.

If you want to increase the **Project's** heap size you must go to your project's **Properties / Run / VM Options**, and in the text box add the arguments.

Comment: Just to make sure I didn't phrase it badly: will this increase the heap space for the apps Netbeans open or just Netbeans itself? The memory-problem is with (a well-coded) algorithm that tries to solve an NP-Hard problem.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat You are right. This will only increase NetBean's heap space. I'll edit my answer with new data.