# How to I change the default JVM heap size on OS X?

Tags: macos, java

I am looking for a way to change the default JVM memory settings on OS X, not for a specific application.

And, yes I know that each application can override this.

Currently running Java 1.6 on OS X 10.8

Comment: similar to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63223/how-do-i-increase-the-heap-size-for-netbeans-and-any-app-run-via-netbeans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

1. Go to **Applications / Utilities** and open the **Java Preferences**.
2. Select the Java version you're interested in.
3. Hit **Options** and add the *Heap size* argument, which is `-Xmx` followed by amount of memory you want it to have. (e.g. `-Xmx1024`).

Comment: i just tried your method , everything's fine but when i open the java preferences there's is no "Option" button. Thank you
Running with a Macbook pro 13" , Os 10.8.3 , 2,5 GHz Intel Core i5, 8go 1600n MHz DDR3
Java 7 Maj 17.

Answer (score 1):

Three options for configuring JVM's Heap:

I) System Preferences -> Click on Java icon. 
[image]

Then go to "Java" tab -> View... -> Add "-Xmx9000M" to Runtime Parameters section. 
[image]

II) Increase it in Tomcat: 
Follow these instructions= https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/How-to-increase-the-Java-Heap-size-in-Tomcat-Application-Server

To increase the Java heap size in Tomcat, follow the instructions below:

1) Go to /bin and create a file named http://setenv.sh for Linux systems or setenv.bat for Windows.

2) Inside the setenv file, use the following format to set the heap size using the following parameters:
Linux:
  export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms4096M -Xmx4096M"

III) Increase it in the GUI (Intellij or Eclipse).